# How to wire circuit DC Motor with LED

Tags: wiring

I'm trying to learn a bit more about forward voltage and Ohm's law but I'm not sure how to wire this circuit.

I have:

- [One 4.5 DC motor](http://www.jaycar.com.au/Electromechanical-Components/Mechatronics/Motors-%26-Gearboxes/Hobby-Motor---Medium-Torque/p/YM2707) (Operating Volts: 1.5- 4.5V, Nominal Volts: 4.5V, Current (no load): 0.25A)
- [Three 5mm LEDs](http://www.jaycar.com.au/Active-Components/Optoelectronics/Standard-LEDs/LED-5mm-Red-Waterclear-10000mcd/p/ZD0156) (IF Typical (mA)20, IF Max Continuous (mA)50, VF Typical (V)2.1) -
- One 3 - 12VDC Switchmode Plugpack (Output voltage: 3, 4.5, 5, 6, 7.5, 9, Output current: 1000mA (max))

Do I use the power at 4.5V and run the motor and the LEDs in parallel?

Do I need resistors on the LEDs?

Comment: `IF Max Continuous (mA)50,` LED current should be limited to  this value. You may consider ignoring DC Motor until you are able to appreciate ohms law using LED, supply and resistors.

Comment: @Umar, but if I wire the motor and the LEDs in parallel, surely I don't need to cut the amperage down from 1A to 50mA? That was my question.

Comment: Yes and yes. One resistor for each LED : none for the motor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect DC Motor and LED in parallel with the resistor in series with LED. LED can  draw current about 24 mA (4.5 V - 2.1 V)/ (100 Ohms). 
If resistor is not placed in series with it, The LED will eventually get over heated and gets destroyed. use a fly back diode in parallel with motor if it is unidirectional.  If Power is set to 4.5 V, then using a 100 ohm resistor with LED is recommended.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOWSEp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

LED do not have a datasheet, so assuming typical Vf for calculation.

Answer (score 1):

You should wire things like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUtkoa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You require a current limiting resistor in series with each LED, to limit the current in that LED to 20 mA.  The motor will draw whatever current it requires - no need for a current limiting resistor for it, as long as you don't feed it more than its rated voltage.